# Limit of function composition $\lim_{x \to 0}\ln(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \ln [\lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}]$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\ln(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \ln [\lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}]$$

While attempting to understand the approximation of $e$, I ended up at the above step where the RHS is derived from the following theorem.

If $f$ is continuous at $c$ and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} g=c$,  we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} f\circ g= f( \lim_{x\rightarrow b} g)$.

Here, $f= \ln x$,  $g=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $b=0$. As $x\rightarrow b$, $g\rightarrow 1^\infty$. I have read online that one raised to the power of Infinity( and not undefined as $x\neq b$ ) is indeterminate. If that is true, $\ln$ cannot be continuous at $c$( indeterminate ). How can we then take the limit as shown in the picture?

---

Does, "If $f$ is continuous at $c$ and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} g=c$,  we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} f\circ g= f( \lim_{x\rightarrow b} g)$" hold if $f$ is not continuous at $c$ but its limit is c?

I believe it does as per the formal definition of the limit.

Comment: In your example chosen as $x\to b$ the function $g(x) \to e$ and not to $1^{\infty}$ and log is continuous at $e$. In general if $g$ is positive as $x\to a$ then $\log\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} \log g(x) $ irrespective of the fact whether $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $ exists or not. There is a particular caveat here. In general the limit operation always commutes with the action of a continuous function.

Comment: Below, I have tried to arrive at the result by making an assumption. I'm hoping to know if that is acceptable or not.

Comment: Can  anything be said about the second part of the question?

Comment: When $f$ is not continuous then you have the following theorem: if $g(x) \to c$ as $x\to b$ and $g(x) \neq c$ as $x\to b$ then $\lim_{x\to b} f(g(x)) $ has same behavior as that of $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) $. Here we don't assume anything about continuity of $f$ or $ g$.

Comment: This makes me confident.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common confusion. Here's the thing: "*indeterminate*" does **NOT** mean "*undefined*" (or "*does not exist*"). Roughly speaking, we say that a limit is an ***indeterminate form*** if from the parts of the expression we can't automatically deduce the value of the limit. For example:

- $\frac{6}{3}$ is not an indeterminate form, because it's definitely equal to $2$. This means that if you have a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=6$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=3$, then you can for sure conclude that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=2$.
- But $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form. This means that if you have a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, then the result can be different depending on the specific functions $f$ and $g$. Note that I did **NOT** say "undefined"! Such a limit may turn out to be undefined, or to be equal to any real number, or to be infinite. For example:
  $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^4}=+\infty, \quad \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1, \quad \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^4}{x^2}=0, \quad \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{18x^2}{2x^2}=9, \quad \text{etc,}$$
  where all these limits, if you first look at their numerators and denominators separately, are of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Another way to rephrase this: calling a limit "*indeterminate*" is **NOT** the answer! It only means that we can't deduce the answer by (roughly speaking) basic observation. At this point the answer is still unknown to us; so we have to do some more work, possibly using more advanced techniques, to find the limit (or demonstrate that it doesn't exist).

As you correctly pointed out, $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form. But you misinterpreted what that means. It only means that we **don't know yet** the answer to this particular limit (as opposed to seeing something like $2^3$, when we'd immediately conclude that the answer is $8$). We still have no idea whether $c$ exists or not! For this reason, we **don't know yet** whether the theorem applies here or not.

So we have to do some more work to find the inside limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}$. One way or another — (insert some solution here) — we can find that actually $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}=e$. So our $c=e$, and since $f(x)=\ln x$ is continuous at $c=e$, **now we know** that the theorem is perfectly applicable here.

Comment: The term indeterminate makes good sense to me now. I think I can now do it the following way. Let's assume that $f$ is continuous at $c$, and that the limit of $g$ exists at $x=0$ and is $c$. We know that $f'(1)$ is 1. The first principle of differentiation gets us to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  f(g) =1$, where $f$ and $g$ are functions defined above. The theorem now tells us that $f(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g)=1$. It is reasonable to state that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g=e$, as per the definition of the natural logarithm.

Comment: To confirm our assumption, we look at $e$. $f$ is indeed continuous at $e$, as per the definition of natural logarithm. Does this complete the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\ln[(1+x)^{1/x}]=\frac{\ln(1+x)}x.$$
One really shouldn't apply L'Hospital's rule to this, but what happens if one does?

Comment: I haven't arrived at L'Hospital's rule yet. I cannot discuss this.

Comment: Could you draw the graphs of $y=\ln(1+x)$ and $y=x$ then, and see how they compare?

Comment: I can say that you have shifted $\ln$ one unit to the left. Both graphs pass through the origin.

Comment: Could you comment on my lines, "I have read online that one raised to the power of Infinity( and not undefined as $x\neq b$ ) is indeterminate. If that is true, $\ln$ cannot be continuous at $c$( indeterminate )"? I believe here is where my problem lies.